# Can't Add Classes With intersectionObserver JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, html, css, intersection-observer

I once tried to follow a tutorial from FireShip about Scroll Animations. I followed everything that is in the video, but somehow can't get the JavaScript code to work. When I run it, it's just a black screen without the h1 elements slowly showing up by decreasing the opacity I then figured out that my JavaScript can't add classes to my h1 elements using classList.add() when my viewport is intersecting with the element.

Here is the HTML, CSS and JavaScript used:

```js
const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      entry.target.classList.add('show');
    } else {
      entry.target.classList.remove('show');
    }
  });
});

const hiddenElements = document.querySelectorAll('.hide');

hiddenElements.forEach((el) => observer.observe(el));
```

```css
* {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  background-color: black;
}
section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-size: 3em;
}

.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.show {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Cool Scrolls</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script differ src="script.js"></script>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <section>
    <h1 class="hide">Introducing</h1>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h1 class="hide">The One And Only</h1>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h1 class="hide">"Hello World"</h1>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there something wrong with them?

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine on my device, without any changes. Does your browser support `IntersectionObserver`?

Comment: My Google Chrome is up to date lol

Comment: How strange. Stack Overflow can run it flawlessly, but my Google Chrome can't. I should make a new question about this.

Comment: SO does add stuff. What have you got as document declaration and in your head element?

Comment: Either: 1) Wrap your JS code inside `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ...)` or 2) Move your `script.js ` to the bottom of your code, right before `</body>`, or ... 3) Change `<script differ ...>` to `<script defer ...>` ;)

Comment: THANK YOU , FIDDLE. I can't express how thankful I am. It works

Comment: Glad I could help. If I may offer a suggestion - feel free to answer your own question, and explain how you resolved the issue you were facing. This is just so that other users who might face a similar problem can (easily) find the solution via Google or StackOverflow search.